# remove new line break from top and replace with remaining text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, .net

[text area control contains new line break so i should remove that new line break from top and replace with remaining string like image two[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IGXY.png)

This images shows

Comment: Give us part of your code (html, css)

Answer (score 0):

You could trim it:

```
$('textarea').val(function(_, val){
  return val.trim();
});
```

But better would be to avoid it server side, before rendering it on client.

Answer (score 0):

Please use jQuery trim() function to remove line breaks. Below code may be help you.

```
var obj=$("#textareaID");
obj.val(obj.val().trim())
```

http://live.datatables.net/hucuwemi/1/watch